# html row isn't drawing line

Tags: html, css

[html]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
            Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

            <title>table</title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="Hyunjae.Park">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablestyle.css" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

            <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        </head>

        <body>
            <table id="roomlist_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th><th>Users</th><th>Organizers</th><th>Time</th><th>Explanation</th><th>Adjustment</th><th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>1/12</th>
                        <th>Test, Man</th>
                        <th>17:00~18:00</th>
                        <th>Test Explanation</th>
                        <th><button>Modify</button><button>Network</button><button>Enter</button></th>
                        <th><a href="#">delete</a></th>
                    </tr>
<tr class="row">
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>1/12</th>
                        <th>Test, Man</th>
                        <th>17:00~18:00</th>
                        <th>Test Explanation</th>
                        <th><button>Modify</button><button>Network</button><button>Enter</button></th>
                        <th><a href="#">delete</a></th>
                    </tr>
<tr class="row">
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>1/12</th>
                        <th>Yourself</th>
                        <th>17:00~18:00</th>
                        <th>Test Explanation</th>
                        <th><button>Modify</button><button>Network</button><button>Enter</button></th>
                        <th><a href="#">delete</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <!-- <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Roomtype</th>
                        <th>Organizers</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Explanation</th>
                        <th></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>Seminar</th>
                        <th>Test, Man</th>
                        <th>17:00~18:00</th>
                        <th>Test Explanation</th>
                        <th><button>Modify</button><button>Delete</button><button>Enter</button></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>1/12</th>
                        <th>Test, Man</th>
                        <th>17:00~18:00</th>
                        <th>Test Explanation</th>
                        <th><button>Modify</button><button>Network</button><button>Enter</button></th>
                        <th><a href="#">delete</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

[css]

```
#roomlist_table{
    font-size: 11pt;
    border-top: 1px solid #353b55;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 730px;
    border-left: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
    border-right: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
}
#roomlist_table thead{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#roomlist_table thead tr{
    height: 30px;
}
#roomlist_table tbody tr{
    height: 50px;
}
.row{
    border: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
}
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/15/

the funnly thing is if i run this in my local, it doesn't show any line in chrome, but in jsfiddle demo, it shows one line.

[Edit]

JSFiddle ISN't showing the full line, not only chrome. any good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you miss a equal symbol in tr class declaration:

your line for 2nd and 3rd `tr` is `<tr class "row">`, the correct line is  `<tr class="row">`.
Maybe Chrome doesn't tolerate such a mistake.

Second, I don't know why the border style in `tr` doesn't work, but you can have this trick for the same effect: style `.row>th` having `border-top` as follow:

```
#roomlist_table {
    font-size: 11pt;
    border-top: 1px solid #353b55;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 730px;
    border-left: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
    border-right: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
}
#roomlist_table thead {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#roomlist_table thead tr {
    height: 30px;
}
#roomlist_table tbody tr {
    height: 50px;
}
.row>th {
    border-top: 1px solid #bcc0c9;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P2GZX/15/

Comment: Yes, put your HTML in http://validator.w3.org/ and it will check for any mistakes in the markup. `Error Line 17, Column 15: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter
    <tr class "row">
✉
Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value".`

Comment: Thanks for the advise i changed it all to <tr class "row"> but still showing no line :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit your css for "row"

```
.row {
  outline: thin solid #bcc0c9;
}
```

Please let me know if this doesnt help.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, this works, but why is it thicker than other lines? I tried to change outline: 1px solid #bcc0c9; but still thicker than other lines

Comment: will "dotted" work for you?. .row {outline: thin dotted #bcc0c9;}